# Jenkins configuration to download jar file from Maven central and put it in Nexus

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I have an environment and we skipped to download all the dependencies from Maven central. So we need to **create a Jenkins job** and it has a parameter with detail for which component jar it should **download from central**, and if we provide that details it should download and it **needs to be put in a particular repository in Nexus.**

I'm totally new to this environment, can someone provide inputs of any plugins to use or some scripts to be used ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Nexus can transparently mirror maven central jo you just need to tell maven to use that. Will that be an option?

Comment: Thanks for your response. We are going to stop the mirroring, and If a development team needs some binaries from central, they can directly run this Jenkins job, so that the binary will be present in Nexus repo, that's how it is planned.

Comment: But why? This is counterproductive

Comment: Actually due to some version compatibility issues with binaries its planned like this, that's why planned to run the job only if we require update of particular binary

Comment: My gut feeling is that this is a brittle solution to an X-Y problem, but difficult to say without more information.

Comment: Yes please, may I know what info is required ?

Comment: Somebody has decided that this is the best solution to a problem you have only described very briefly.  I would suggest you open a new question where you describe this problem in detail and ask for suggestions.  There might be a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not so trivial as it might seem. At first glance there are two plugins which might help:

- [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) - may download artifact from repository
- [maven-deploy-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) - may upload artifact to repository

however that won't work due to a "couple" of reasons:

- artifacts have dependencies - that is not enough to transfer single artifact and tell developers something like "well, now you may use it" - you need to traverse all transitive dependencies and transfer them as well
- artifacts have classifiers - most useful of them are `javadoc` and `sources`, and if artifact has those useful classifiers it is a good idea to transfer them as well
- artifact descriptor (pom) may refer to another (parent) pom - there is a dedicated cauldron in the hell for developers who do not flatten poms when publishing artifacts, however we can do nothing with that - we need to transfer parent poms as well
- dependencies may have snapshot or range versions - there is another dedicated cauldron in the hell for developers who use such dependencies

and the reasonings mentioned above lead us to the idea that we need a specialised software (read: basic shell scripting won't work) which is capable to transfer *consistent copy* of artifact from one repository to another. And all the time I did believe the guys, who are responsible for such decisions (create own trusted repository and manage it), do have idea how to do that properly, unfortunately it seems that they don't.

I have [tried to implement some PoC using maven API](https://github.com/andreybpanfilov/reposync) which is capable to transfer *consistent copies* (transitive dependencies, pom and parent poms) of artifacts across repositories, hope that will help.

```
% mvn tel.panfilov.maven:reposync-maven-plugin:0.1.0:single \
 -Dartifact=org.springframework:spring-tx:5.3.22 \
 -DsourceRepositories=central::default::https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 \
 -DtargetRepository=local::::http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases \
 -Dtransitive=true \
 -DdryRun=true \
 -DsyncSources=true \
 -DsyncJavadoc=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- reposync-maven-plugin:0.1.0:single (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Processing Dependency {groupId=org.springframework, artifactId=spring-tx, version=5.3.22, type=jar}
[INFO] Source repositories: [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases+snapshots)]
[INFO] Target repository: local (http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/, default, releases+snapshots)
[INFO] Discovered 16 artifacts
[INFO]  org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.22
...
[INFO]  org.springframework:spring-tx:pom:5.3.22
[INFO] Found 16 missing artifacts
[INFO]  org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.22
...
[INFO]  org.springframework:spring-tx:pom:5.3.22
[INFO] Dry run, exiting
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```